# What does "See [H4.3]" means in an RFC?

Tags: rtsp, rfc

On https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2326#page-19, it has this section:

```
4.3 Message Body

   See [H4.3]
```

and many others saying `See H[x.y]`.

What does this `H` mean? Where can I find this section to read more about? I could not find in the appendix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is referring to the HTTP/1/1 specification.

The note is a little bit hidden in the spec but there is section near the top on notation:

> 2 Notational Conventions
>
> Since many of the definitions and syntax are identical to HTTP/1.1,
> this specification only points to the section where they are defined
> rather than copying it. For brevity, [HX.Y] is to be taken to refer
> to Section X.Y of the current HTTP/1.1 specification (RFC 2068 [2]).

I am guessing you know but just in case - this RFC has been superseded and obsoleted by the later RTSP RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7826

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'm using the old one because many cameras still use RTSP 1.0, but I'm also reading the 2.0